# SSL connect error in shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am using R, version 3.3.1. Today, I have made an account on shinyapps.io and deployed my shiny app: https://forensis.shinyapps.io/Forensis/

As you can see, it is a simple app. It has one input (OIB) and several outputs. It is importannt to say that query to REST DATA API appears in every output. So I took, OIB and ask some data from API, where OIB is input.

When I run my app localy everything works fine, but when I run it on web it produces error `SSL connect error` every time I try to execute the OIB (try it with OIB: 93335620125).

**EDIT** I am posting example of one query to DATA API (others are the same):

```
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
for (i in 1:length(report_exe())) { 
reqOP <- rbind(fromJSON(toJSON(content(GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/oibstatus/", add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxx"), query = list(oib = report_exe())), type = "application/json"), null = "null"), flatten = TRUE)) 
req[[i]] <- reqOP 
} 
json <- do.call(rbind, req)

json <- as.data.frame(json) 
oib_status <- as.data.frame(lapply(f1(json), unlist), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Here is an example of one call:    `for (i in 1:length(report_exe())) {
      reqOP <- rbind(fromJSON(toJSON(content(GET(url = "https://api.data-api.io/v1/oibstatus/",
                                                 add_headers('x-dataapi-key' = "xxxx"),
                                                 query = list(oib = report_exe())), type = "application/json"), null = "null"), flatten = TRUE))
      req[[i]] <- reqOP
    }
    json <- do.call(rbind, req)
    json <- as.data.frame(json)
  
    oib_status <- as.data.frame(lapply(f1(json), unlist), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)`

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, got in touch with the Support team at Rstudio and they've updated the shinyapps.io servers to use `openssl` over `gnutls` for SSL handling. Try to re-deploy your app - chances are that it will work okay now!